# Which communities do not allow women to drive cars?

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, vehicles-transportation, communities

Which communities do not allow women to drive cars?

I know the Belzer hassidim do not allow this, but I do not know about any other communities.

Comment: I believe the justification of this restriction is tznius but my question is also about non hassidic (mitnagdim) community. I will change the title to make it better.

Comment: What is the tznius reasoning behind such a prohibition?

Comment: That driving is not a modest behavior.

Comment: [Shevet haLevi 4:1:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1414&pgnum=9)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin b"H!

Comment: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/64346/1719

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. The Shulchan Aruch (73:1) and Rambam states that a woman shouldn't leave the house too much. And of course, you have Shevet haLevi 4:1:2. Apparently, humras regarding tznius are recommended by Rashi.

It seems that Belz, Satmar, Viznitz, Skver, Bobov and Pupa do not allow this. But I don't know whether this is official or just an implicit minhag, nor whether it's universal in those groups.

Source: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/women-driving-1

Comment: I have no idea and if this is a joke I do not find it funny.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I believe driving and walking are not similar. I am not sure, but from what I have read, it seems that driving is seen as a manly activity. Also, it seems that even for men, some rabbanim in the last century were not totally in favor of driving. Maybe it was too manly for men too. I think the best would be to ask directly a belzer hassid.

Comment: I heard that the reason is that they would have to sit in the front (obviously), which is like being exposed in a storefront window. The same communities won't have females as front seat passengers either.