# Chasidish women driving vs. walking

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, chasidut-hasidism, vehicles-transportation

In the Chasidish communities in which women [don't drive](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/which-communities-do-not-allow-women-to-drive-cars). Does the community hold because of tznius (modesty). If it's because of tznius (modesty) isn't she exposing her body even more by walking on the street than if she would be in a car? Did the women consent to this or were they forced to? Do they feel it's a discrimination to them?

Comment: @Yishai, I've edited this question so that it's only a follow-up to that one and not a dupe of it.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/which-communities-do-not-allow-women-to-drive-cars#comment74714_29772

Answer (score 0):

A possible thought is that women must often interact with other men in other cars, at intersections etc. Walking requires much less interaction with members of the opposite gender.

Comment: That's true. However, let's say you're walking down the street and at the other end you see this attractive women. You wouldn't have seen her full attractiveness if she was driving in a car.

Comment: Huh? What interactions are there while driving? I can barely see the other driver

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: I was talking to Yehudah.

Comment: @shmuelbrin don't ask me, I didn't invent this minhag nor do I hold of it. However, I do believe the people who did invent it could have reasoned that driving has more communication with surrounding people then walking.