# Are women allowed to drive?

Tags: minhag, women, chasidut-hasidism, vehicles-transportation

Prompted by [this article](http://www.timesofisrael.com/equal-rights-board-slams-uk-hasidic-ban-on-women-drivers/) is there **any** basis for not allowing woman to drive? Can this practice even be termed a 'minhag'? If so, what is the motivation behind this 'tradition'?

As quoted from the article:

> One local rabbi told the paper that he supported the policy because it upheld the community’s traditional values. “It’s always been regarded in Hasidic circles as not the done thing for a lady to drive,” he commented.

Comment: It's obviously an infiltration from Reform since before the rise of the Reform movement in the 19th century, Jewish women never drove. Also, chodosh assur min hatorah.

Comment: The Rama in Orach Chaim 472:4 says: > הגה: וכל הנשים שלנו מיקרי חשובות (מרדכי ריש פ' ע"פ ורבינו ירוחם),
> **אך לא נהגו** Those who forbid women to drive would presumably understand this to mean that while women are important, they do not drive [נהג=driver].

Comment: I think it's a dup

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/which-communities-do-not-allow-women-to-drive-cars

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, you missed a whole comment discussion about that very topic (it was now cleaned up). It has been decided that this question lives one, the other one is a dup of this one, and the one that asks about which communities do it is separate.

Comment: @Yishai I was thinking of the one you just linked.

Comment: In my preception of Tora and men-women issues, this question shouldn't exists. BIG -1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Shevet HaLevi 4:1 s.q. 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1414&pgnum=9) by [Rav Shmuel Wosner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_Wosner) writes that "experience has taught him" that it is proper to completely forbid women driving because the activity of learning to drive leads to immodest behavior, and the driving itself violates the notion of "All glorious is the king's daughter within the palace" ([Tehilim 45:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2645.htm#14)). He also points to the Talmud Pesachim 3 that is not "a woman's way" to ride on a donkey, and says that even though the two activities are different, the idea that it is not "a woman's way" is still present for reasons that are "difficult to explain in writing."

He then goes on the blame the prevalence of this sin for the high rate of fatalities on the roads in Israel.

[Rav Binyamin Zilber](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A8) in [Az Nidberu Volume 13 #20](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14707&st=&pgnum=253) takes issue with this and says that in Talmudic times women rode on donkeys, it just isn't a nice image due to the standard riding position requiring spiting the legs over the animal and says that such stringency when not required leads to leniency when required.

I should also take issue with the statement "It’s always been regarded in Hasidic circles as not the done thing for a lady to drive" as the Lubavitcher Rebbetzin [drove her own car (footnote 135)](https://books.google.com/books?id=z8MNBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA515&lpg=PA515#v=onepage&q&f=false). So it should really read "in **some** Hasidic circles."

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/which-communities-do-not-allow-women-to-drive-cars?lq=1#comment74582_29765

Comment: http://www.slate.com/blogs/xx_factor/2012/07/17/german_parking_lot_and_women_drivers_are_ladies_actually_bad_behind_the_wheel_.html

Comment: @DoubleAA, his argument isn't that they get into more accidents. Its that the prevalence of the sin makes the roads dangerous. Please don't take this answer as an endorsement, it is just information the question requested.

Comment: I still think my answer had a more substantive source than the Shevet haLevi's but ok

Comment: @DoubleAA, anyway the science [isn't so clear on that](http://www.laweekly.com/news/women-drivers-are-worse-than-men-according-to-study-2396924), not that I think it matters one way or another.

Comment: Funny thing is, if somehow driving is connected to pisuk raglayim, then men shouldn't drive either as the Chazzon Ish believed the issue applied to men too which is why they should wear long coats:)

Comment: @user6591, well then I'm sure self driving cars, like internet filters, will become a required religious purchase.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Roi Tamir Shlit"a in his sefer מאיר נתיבים, a compendium of Halachos of safety and driving, quotes both Rav Chaim Kanievsky and Rav Wosner forbidding women from driving as it is a prohibition of Klei Gever- utensils which are exclusive to men.

Comment: Do you know what communities this psak was intended for? Klei Gever is a time and location specific Halacha.

Comment: Could be. Just quoting. Bli neder I will get the exact info for it.

Comment: Kli gever? What about a pen? The majority of authors used to be men!

Comment: @bondonk like I said I'm just quoting

Comment: @bondonk It's like that old expression: "you can't spell..." eh... never mind.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago, I asked a Satmar Chassid who lives in my neighborhood about why women do not drive.

He explained that one of the reasons is that it is not considered *derech tzni'ut* - a way of modesty. He surmises that perhaps part of this origin was that when cars were developed, they had higher entrances - i.e., you had to step **up** (climb) into the car. When doing so, women had to raise their legs, thus revealing the lower part of their leg (and if wearing a loose skirt, perhaps, a higher area was also revealed.) Hence, perhaps, that concern lent itself to the original prohibition.

Another reason is that driving and cars' concerns was considered a "man's" role. Consider, for example, young boys and teenagers' interest in cars; stats showing few women drivers, in general for numerous decades until a spike around the 60's - 70's (Neither of my grandparents ever drove; my mom never drove; none of my aunts, except 1 of them drove - there's some consistency, I think); how few female auto mechanics / auto dealers, etc.

Also, a general consideration is that women should be at or near home and outside, minimally. Thus, it's deemed that driving a car is unnecessary.

As for being a passenger, they are passengers for "minimal" purposes, and it's almost always with the entire family, including the kids. When they attend weddings, often even the infants come with them, even to a friend's wedding.

There may also have been a security concern regarding sole women drivers. They are more likely to be harmed than men, and their own cars could be used as the very means or place of attack, as well.

For various reasons, not having women drive has become a long-established tradition that numerous Hasidic rebbe's enforce and the community follows the rebbe's policy.

It is debatable as to whether this would be "halacha" or minhag. It depends on your analysis. Personally, I would consider this "halacha" as there is a halacha to follow rules of modesty. If this is the rebbe's interpretation of what fits into these rules, then, for these Hasidim, it is their halacha.

Comment: According to your explanation, it is perhaps a halacha for women not to climb into the original model of car which forced them to raise their skirts, but even if it has become an established tradition in some circles to forbid it in other cars, that would still only be a minhag by definition. Halacha would still allow women in modern cars that do not have the modesty problems.

Comment: Then they shouldn't be passengers either

Comment: @ShmuelBrin See edited answer, above, that addresses being passengers vs. drivers. It's more than a modesty issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Amnon Yitzchak [argues](http://www.vosizneias.com/146342/2013/11/13/jerusalem-rabbi-amnon-yitzhak-drivers-seat-is-for-men-only/) that men should only drive cars as it is analgous to a horse drawn carriage which where traditionally driven by men, making it a modesty issue.

Comment: Where is the tradition for men to drive carriages documented? Can you clarify what aspect of Jewish law he is appealing to? Minhag haMakom? Kli Gever? Dat Yehudit?

Comment: @doubleaa, Modesty. Added to answer.

Comment: @doubleaa, re documentation, he doesn't say, but it is still true, if you were ever around central park when they have them. It used to be a jpb anagous to a taxi driver. I doubt many women did that in the 19th century.

Comment: Odd. I don't understand why the way things were done in the past determines what is modest now. Modesty is about breaking from the norm and standing out. His argument seems lacking in any halachic basis.

Comment: @DoubleAA, modesty also has an objective component. Not sure why that would apply here specifically. Or perhaps his point is that this is the community standard in some communities (it isn't clear in the article if he was making a normative global statement, or defending the practice).

Comment: I wasn't aware of any such objective component. (Random Torah laws to do X or cover body part X are Gezeros HaMelech. For instance, married women cover their hair bc God said so whether or not doing so is considered modest (in most times and places it probably is).)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I would have to check where, but I remember seeing the Lubavitcher Rebbe arguing that carrying a sword would be immodest for a woman, even in a society of warrior women (as described in Tamid). It also seems implausible off hand that were societal norms to allow it, walking around naked would be just fine (as in Roman times).

Comment: It seems implausible bc it's really different for you. We're not talking about a nudist colony in california. I mean like an african tribe where women and men never developed shirts (they exist). You'd criticize those women as immodest? No one there thinks twice for even a moment about their breasts hanging out everywhere. It's not even something they think about. (I'm assuming for the moment _arguendo_ that there is no Gezerat HaMelech which makes such a situation impossible.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think the Torah would require more cover than that, yes. No time to gather the sources, but I think there were already answers around there which addressed it. If you say there is a Gezerat HaMelech, then I'm just calling that "objective standard", and we are talking past each other.

Comment: If there is a gezerat hamelech to not drive carriages, then a) that's bizarre and b) citing past custom is irrelevant when you can cite me a talmud.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I guess like wearing swords. I agree it would be bizarre.